# CLI of Inkscape not working from regular PowerShell

Tags: powershell, pdf, symbolic-link, latex, inkscape

### End goal:

Automatially convert all .drawio.svg files in working directory to .pdf-files while compiling a LaTeX-document.

---

I have VS Code with LaTeX Workshop set up as my LaTeX-Environment and recently discovered that I can use the inofficial [draw.io-extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=hediet.vscode-drawio) to directly generate the diagrams inside of VS Code without the need to use another software or a website. Now I want to automatically convert the generated `some-filename.drawio.svg` to a `same-filename.pdf` that I then can include as a floating figure inside my document.
For that I have read that I need InkScape, so I installed it and put a symlink to the `inkscape.com` file from the Inkscape binary folder inside my binary folder that is located at `C:\Binaries` which is already in my PATH as I didn't want to fill my path with all that extra stuff that comes with the programs I only need one binary of.

The first problem I encouter is that the CLI only works if I am in an elevated PowerShell-Prompt, not in a regular one. Is there an easy explanation and fix for this or did I mess up somewhere?
Next, how can I tell VS Code to automatically generate the `pdf`-file, when I save the `.drawio.svg`-file and/or when I compile the LaTeX-document?

I can provide any more information needed, but I hope this outline explains the problem.

Comment: Sounds as if the latex `svg` package might be useful for you. Behind the scenes, this packages uses inkscape to convert all includes `.svg` files to pdf when you compile your document (you will still need to fix your path problems first...)

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I saw that package, but it always said that it needs the image to be exported to some kind of `.pdf_tex` files via the gui first. I'd like to somehow circumvent that. Any idea about the PATH problem?

Comment: If the document is compiled with shell-escape enabled, the package will exactly do this conversation: It uses inkscape to convert the svg file into a pdf and a pdf_tex file.

Comment: But that would mean to give more rights to the extension and the latexpdf executable which is something that I'd rather not do. There is to much that can go wrong by giving programs that have full write access to a directory and everything below even more elevated rights.